# regex to capture overlapping matches preceding any number with more than 4 digits

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a regular expression to pick 30 characters present before a number which has more than 4 digits in below text. Here is my code:

```
text = "I went and I bought few tickets and ticket numbers 100000,100001 and 100002.I bought them for 200,300 and 400 USD. Box office collections were 55555555 USD"

reg=".{0,30}(?:[\d]+[ .]?){5,}"
regc=re.compile(reg)
res=regc.findall(text)
```

This is giving below partial results

[image]

I am getting 30 characters before 100000 only.

How do I get 30 characters before 100001 and how do I also get 30 characters before 100002?

Comment: What are the expected results? With my try to fix it, I got `['D. Box office collections were 55555555', 'cket numbers 100000,100001 and 100002', 'ets and ticket numbers 100000,100001', 'few tickets and ticket numbers 100000']`

Comment: Do you have to use regex to capture the characters that precede all the numbers with more than 4 digits in your string?

Comment: @Wiktor yes that will help.. Also can you help me to extract 100001 and 100002 along with 100000 like in first string..

Comment: @benvc yes I want to capture characters before 4 digits number

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for any 30 chars in front except line breaks, ?= positive look ahead, but not including in the catching group

```
/.{30}(?=100001)/g
```

https://regexr.com/4293v

Answer (score 0):

Since you need overlapping matches, you need to use lookarounds. However, lookbehinds in `re` are of fixed width, so, you may utilize a hack: reverse the string, use a regex with a lookahead, and then reverse the matches:

```
import re
rev_rx = r'((?:\d+[ .]?){5,})(?=(.{0,30}))'
text="I went and I bought few tickets and ticket numbers 100000,100001 and 100002.I bought them for 200,300 and 400 USD. Box office collections were 55555555 USD"
results = [ "{}{}".format(y[::-1], x[::-1]) for x, y in re.findall(rev_rx, text[::-1]) ]
print(results)
# => ['D. Box office collections were 55555555', 'cket numbers 100000,100001 and 100002', 'ets and ticket numbers 100000,100001', 'few tickets and ticket numbers 100000']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/pyYSRa).

The `((?:\d+[ .]?){5,})(?=(.{0,30}))` regex matches and captures into Group 1 five or more sequences of 1+ digits and an optional space or comma. Then, the positive lookahead checks if there are 0 to 30 chars in the string. The substring is captured into Group 2. So, all you need is concatenate reversed Group 2 and Group 1 values to get the matches you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by combining some simple regex with string methods to get the 30 characters that precede any number with more than 4 digits (rather than using more complex regex to both find the matches and capture the desired characters).

The example below uses regex to find all the numbers with more than 4 digits, then uses `str.find()` to get the position of each match in the original text so you can slice the preceding 30 characters:

```
import re

text = "I went and I bought few tickets and ticket numbers 100000,100001 and 100002.I bought them for 200,300 and 400 USD. Box office collections were 55555555 USD"

patt = re.compile(r'\d{5,}')
nums = patt.findall(text)
matches = [text[:text.find(n)][-30:] for n in nums]

print(matches)
# OUTPUT (shown on multiple lines for readability)
# [
#     'ew tickets and ticket numbers ',
#     'ets and ticket numbers 100000,',
#     'ket numbers 100000,100001 and ',
#     '. Box office collections were '
# ]
```